# how to transfer data between file.cs in winform?

Tags: c#

I started learning winform. I have created a project from visual studio 2019 but when creating the textbox from the file form1.cs, I don't know how to get the programs.cs file to receive data from the textbox or a button click event.

Comment: Your best bet is to find any Windows Forms sample. In general, the `program.cs` file does nothing but instantiate an instance of your form class and then start it up. Nearly all the interesting code in a simple Windows Forms app is in your form class.

Comment: You do not need the program.cs to get the form1 data. If you work with a windows application to pass data between 2 forms, there are multi-way, which you could choose one of them. Take a look at these examples : [Example1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/834980/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-other-form-in-windows-form/)  [Example2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms)

Comment: More importantly, by the time control returns to `Program.cs`,  `Form1` is already closed and your app in the middle of shutting down.  As others have said, if you the data or monitor click events, then do so from `Form1.cs`

Answer (score -1):

The Program.cs file is just a main program that start your code or application.

You need to create some other forms and UserControl(s) etc. to make a project or learn.
Your Program.cs file just start a form it can be your main form like this

```
    static void Main()
    {
        bool instanceCountOne = false;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Login());       //here its start your form
    }
```

To add text box or button you can simply drag and drop these from the toolbox (generally in the left side)
To create a event for button click you can simply double click on the button which you put on your Winform
For text box: 
1. Right click to your text box.
2. Go to properties.
3. Click on the event button (⚡ thunderbolt shape)
4. Enter select event like : keypress, keydown etc.

You can use Input to your text box like this:

```
NameOfTextBox.text
```

And use it to your code like this:

```
ProcessData(NameOfTextBox.text);
```

And last your method like this:

```
private void ProcessData(string Data)
{
    //Some code....
}
```